# Non-rigid variety deforms to one defined over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a smooth complex projective variety. Assume there is a smooth complex projective variety deformation equivalent to $V$ but not isomorphic to it.

Is there a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ deformation equivalent to $V$?

Comment: Does the hypothesis mean that there is a non trivial family X to B where one of the fibers is V? If so, you can spread out and specialize down to thr base being a number field but I am not sure you can get to the rationals.

Comment: @Asvin yes non-trivial in the sense of not all fibers being isomorphic

Comment: For instance, if we ask for an Elliptic curve with a torsion point of order 50, then such a thing cannot exist over $\mathbb Q$ even though they exist over $\mathbb C$ and deform in a one parameter farmily. I don't know how to construct an example of an abstract variety but I guess they must exist.

Comment: *Candidate counterexample:* Take a rigid variety $X$ of general type not defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ (for instance, a suitable fake projective plane) and consider $V=X \times C$, where $C$ is a smooth curve of genus $\geq 2$. If one can show that all the deformations of $V$ come from deformations of $C$, then we are done, since there are non-trivial deformations of $V$, and none of them  will be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I was writing this up (using Thm. 4.9 of [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01245076) of Catanese), but the thing I can't prove is that $V$ is not defined over $\mathbf Q$ when $X$ isn't.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: take a rational point  $c \in C$. Then $X$ is isomorphic to the section $$\{(x,\, y) \in X \times C \mid y=c \}.$$ Would not this imply that $X$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ if $V=X \times C$ is?

Comment: Uhm...I guess one problem with this argument is that some deformation of $C$ can have no rational points at all, so you cannot use it to conclude that no deformation of $V$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi In fact, it's not even clear that $C$ needs to be defined over $\mathbf Q$ ― the map $V \to C$ is the unique map to a higher genus curve (if you choose $X$ appropriately), but only up to isomorphism. This gives an obstruction in a (possibly noncommutative) Galois cohomology group to defining $C$ over $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: You can use Mnev / Vakil to give counterexamples.